# Undirected graph edge "relink" measure

Tags: dynamic-data, graph-theory

I wish to characterize a dynamic graph based on the frequency of edges being reformed between vertices and the duration between these relinking instances. I refer to such a measure as 'link repetition'. A high value would indicate that newly formed edges are often reconnecting vertices that were connected recently. A low value would indicate that new edges are being formed between new pairs of vertices, or non recent neighbors.

I have searched a while for a measure of this sort but have found mostly measures dealing with new edges that aren't ever removed. A reference to an existing dynamic graph measure would be ideal. My current solution is just the inverse 'time since last link between i and j' averaged over number of timesteps, but I would like to stick with an established solution if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a counter matrix that increments each time links are reformed between nodes of a graph then base your measures off of that.